Trying to reset an android app to a state with a defined set of app data and settings automatically
I'm developing an automated testing process for an Android app that requires resetting the app to a consistent ground state between test sequences. The workflow is as follows:

Start with the phone in a ground state
Execute a series of test steps
Automatically reset the app to its ground state
Execute a different set of test steps
Repeat

I've encountered challenges in automating the reset process (step 3). I can only access the app through adb.
Here are the approaches I've attempted so far:

Replacing files in the data/data/<app_package> directory with a pre-saved reset state.
Using the pm reset command.
Tried backup using bmgr command (which doesn't work for the particular apps, I am trying to automate: Samsung Contact, Samsung Accounts).
Backup methods like titanium (can not be automated).

I can not switch the operating system. I have rooted my phone. Any insights will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help.

When replacing the files in /data/data<app_package> make sure that you also restore/adapt the Linux user and group owner and the access permissions. If the app was totally uninstalled user and group may have changed. If the owner and Linux access permissions are correctly set I don't see a reason why this shouldn't work (unless your app uses AndroidKeyStore which can not be backuped or restored).
